# Can the main window go to the edge of the screen without a title bar and take up half of the screen?

Tags: qt

Can I resize the main window by moving to the edge of the monitor?
If possible, how?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPppJ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your future questions. For this: I guess the language should be C++, from what i know Qt has no C interface. Also, dont link to another site for images, post them on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.
For your future questions, please refer to the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

I will try to answer your question based on the little information provided:

The feature you're referring to (drag a window to the edge of a screen to "snap" it) is a feature provided by the desktop environment / window manager through which you're running your Qt application (or any GUI application for that matter).
In this case it's a Microsoft Windows feature. No matter what language & libraries you'll be using to create an application (with a window) - this feature will work. You don't need to do anything special in your Qt application. It will just work - as long as your window is resizable.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
May the peace be full

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if this helped you.